# Initialization of var in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, var

Consider below code:

```
public IEnumerable <Country> ListPopulation()
{
    foreach(var continent in Continents)
    {
        var ids = context.continentTable
                   .where(y=>y.Name == continent.name)
                   .select(x=>x.countryId);

    }

    return GetPopulation(ids);// ids is not available here
}

Public IEnumerable<Country>GetPopulation(IQueryable<int> idnumbers)
{

}
```

How can I initialize the **`var ids`** such that I can use it to call `GetPopulation()`?

Answer (score 5):

Well, the main problem has nothing to do with using "var". You've got a foreach loop with the variable declared inside it, and then you're trying to return from *outside* the loop using that variable. What would you expect the value to be?

If you're trying to select *all* the countries, why don't you just do this:

```
public IEnumerable <Country> ListPopulation()
{
    return GetPopulation(context.continentTable.Select(x => x.countryId));
}
```

What's the point of iterating through each of the continents? Or are there countries in the continentTable which aren't referenced by the Continents property which you haven't shown?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are using LINQ in a non-optimal way

```
var ids = from c in context.continetTable
          select c.countryId
```

And then look up based on those ids, however I don't know your datamodel but if your content and country table are linked it would be easier to do this.

```
public IEnumerable <Country> ListPopulation()
{
    return from c in context.contentTable
           select c.Country;
}
```

Where the property Country is a property which is based on the CountryId value.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably follow Jon Skeet's or Nick Berardi's advice and just formulate a better query, but if you actually have a good reason for doing this, here is the answer to your actual question:

To be able to access the variable *ids* after having left the scope of the loop, you have to declare it outside. But you cannot use the *var*-keyword unless you assign to the variable when you declare it. So you have to declare the type explicitly:

```
public IEnumerable <Country> ListPopulation()
{
  IQueryable<Country> ids;
  foreach(var continent in Continents)
  {
    var ids = context.continentTable
              .Where(y=>y.Name == continent.Name)
              .Select(x=>x.countryId);
  }

  return GetPopulation(ids);
}
```